# Presenting file from another website, as a download

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, http-headers

I have a script that parses direct download links from videos in php. I was wondering if it was possible to present this direct link which is not on my server, in a the header as a download so the user doesn't have to right click and save as... If this isn't possible, is it possible to force a right click on a left click?

Comment: How about header("location:".$url); ?

Comment: But mp4 files are usually opened up in a media player within the browser when navigated to

Comment: Theoretically i'ts possible to directly present a download, but in practice it's unworkable (and it may well be illegal).

Answer (score 0):

In PHP I'm using something like the following the present a file if conditions are met, although this is locally stored, you might be able to do something similar:

```
$path = "/path/to/some/file.zip";

header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($path).'"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");
readfile($path); // outputs the content of the file
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Note that, if you want to present a file in a php script, it has to be the first thing that's presented. So if you want to do it without opening a new page, open a php script in an iframe that gives no output other than the file that will be downloaded, or else the download will be corrupt.